# The getter 'price' isn't defined for the type 'String'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

> The getter 'id' isn't defined for the type 'String'.Try importing the library that defines 'id', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named >

I am trying to show my Cart Items when I add them using the cart icon. When I will click on the cart icon it will take me to the **CartScrren** page, where it will show me the selected items.
But I can not get the values from my cart.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../providers/cart.dart'  ;
import '../widgets/cart_items_display.dart';

class CartScreen extends StatelessWidget {
 
  static const route = '/cart';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context);
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Your Cart'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Card(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(25),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Total',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Chip(
                    label: Text(
                      '\$${cart.totalAmount}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
                  TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('Order Now')),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: cart.items.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => CartItemDisplay(
              //Having problem Here**
               cart.items.values.toString()[i].id,
               cart.items.values.toString()[i].price,
               cart.items.values.toString()[i].quantity,
                cart.items.values.toString()[i].title,
                ///////**
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: I want to get the value from my map here but is showing this error]

Below this is my **Cart** here I am using this map.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class CartItem {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final int quantity;
  final double price;

  CartItem({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.price,
  });
}

class Cart with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, CartItem> _items ={} ;
  Map<String, CartItem> get items {
    return  {..._items};
  }
  int get itemCount {
    return _items.length;

  }

  double get totalAmount{
    var total=0.0;
    _items.forEach((key, cartItem) {
      total += cartItem.price*cartItem.quantity;
    });
    

    return total;
  }

  void addItem(String productId, double price, String title) {
    if (_items.containsKey(productId)) {
      _items.update(
          productId,
          (existingCartItem) => CartItem(
              id: existingCartItem.id,
              title: existingCartItem.title,
              quantity: existingCartItem.quantity + 1,
              price: existingCartItem.price));
    } else {
      _items.putIfAbsent(
          productId,
          () => CartItem(
                id: DateTime.now().toString(),
                title: title,
                quantity: 1,
                price: price,
              ));
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

[image: This is my Map]

But if don't use **values.toString()** its throw this error
[image: This happens when I don't use that.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to get cart items from cart value.

```
final cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context);
final cartItems = cart.items.entries.map((e) => e.value).toList();

...

     Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: cartItems.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => CartItemDisplay(
          ////* Change these lines.
           cartItems[i].id,
           cartItems[i].price,
           cartItems[i].quantity,
           cartItems[i].title,
            ///////**
          ),
        ),
      ),
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You use getter for get proprieties:

```
class CartItem {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final int quantity;
  final double price;

  CartItem({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.price,
  });
  
  String get getId => id;
  String get getTitle => title;
  int get getQuantity => quantity;
  double get getPrice => price;
}
```

It is always good to use encapsulation to return a propriety.

```
Expanded(
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: cart.items.length,
    itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => CartItemDisplay(
      //Use getter
      cart.items.values.[i].getId,
      cart.items.values.[i].getPrice,
      cart.items.values.[i].getQuantity.toString(),
      cart.items.values.[i].getTitle.toString(),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: You are making the same mistake as the op. You should be calling the object getters and then call toString. Also `title` and `id` don't need to be converted to string.

Comment: sir, Its showing the same thing as before  ''The getter 'getId' isn't defined for the type 'String'.
Try importing the library that defines 'getId', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'getId'''

Comment: @Md.FazleRabbiI Sorry i forgot to remove the toString ().

Comment: @EliaTolin Indeed I do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this site to build model classes
https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/
i think this site is usefull for create your model class
You can put your json on this site and get the model class